# Compile isc-dhcp-server on linux

Tags: c, compiler-errors, debian, dhcp

I want to compile and debug DHCP server from source code from this repository:
`https://github.com/isc-projects/dhcp`

Everything that I done:

```
./configure

make
```

But I have a lot of errors in this few two commands.

```
/usr/bin/ld: dhcpd-mdb.o:/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server/mdb.c:70: multiple definition of `dhcp_type_host'; dhcpd-omapi.o:/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server/omapi.c:50: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:529: dhcpd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:970: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server'
make: *** [Makefile:496: all-recursive] Error 1
```

But why ? How can I compile isc-dhcp-server ?

My linux distro is debian v11.

UPDATE:

Before compiling isc-dhcp I installed it's requirements.

```
# apt install bind9-dev
```

Then I ran this command instead of make :

```
make -C server install
```

But this errors occur :

```
make: Entering directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server'
Making install in .
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../includes  -I.. -DLOCALSTATEDIR='"/var"'   -g -O2  -Wall -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing -I../includes -I/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/bind/include -MT dhcpd-mdb6.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dhcpd-mdb6.Tpo -c -o dhcpd-mdb6.o `test -f 'mdb6.c' || echo './'`mdb6.c
mdb6.c: In function ‘create_prefix6’:
mdb6.c:1948:3: error: writing 16 bytes into a region of size 1 [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
 1948 |   memcpy(new_ds.buffer->data + ds.len, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../includes/dhcpd.h:97,
                 from mdb6.c:175:
../includes/tree.h:62:16: note: at offset 0 to object ‘data’ with size 1 declared here
   62 |  unsigned char data [1];
      |                ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:738: dhcpd-mdb6.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server'
make: *** [Makefile:921: install-recursive] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/server'
```

This is my configure output result :

```
     ISC DHCP source configure results:
    -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Package:
  Name:          DHCP
  Version:       4.4.2b1

C Compiler:      gcc

Flags:
  DEFS:          -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
  CFLAGS:        -g -O2  -Wall -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing -I$(top_srcdir)/includes -I/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/dhcp/bind/include

DHCP versions:   DHCPv4 and DHCPv6

Features:
  debug:         no
  failover:      yes
  execute:       yes
  binary-leases: no
  dhcpv6:        yes
  delayed-ack:   yes
  dhcpv4o6:      no
  relay-port:    no

Developer:
  ATF unittests : no


Now you can type make to build ISC DHCP
```

SOLUTION

We should clone isc-dhcp service from [here](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp)

Comment: Is this the only output you are getting? Are you getting any errors from configure?

Comment: My questions is updated. No, my configure file ran successfully and suggest me to run make instead of putting many errors.

Comment: Start with the first error. Figure out why `dhcp_type_host` has two definitions.

Comment: Umm it means to i have search in source code and manipulate it ? Is it normal for a standard an open source service ?

Comment: I think we should ignore dhclient for compiling. But how ?

Comment: Did you switch to a stable tag? also i noticed there is another repo linked at the github one with a more recent commits/tags [here](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp)

Comment: Thank you so much. it's works XD. When i compiled dhcp source code from gitlab, it compiled successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are compiling the last commit from an old repo. The github page points at a newer repo at a newer commit at [isc's gitlab site](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp).

You can also switch to the latest stable tag `git checkout v4_4_2_p1` for better stability.

A note, i was able to get it to build using gcc-9, for me the latest stable tag would not build with gcc-10 which is the package version for debian 11. This is an [open issue](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp/-/issues/170)

Comment: Just compiled all ISC DHCP suite from isc's gitlab site mentioned above using gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) and make command on Debian 11. v4_4_2_p1 from ISC download site complained about multiple variable declarations though.